# Using nghttp2 to send APN push notification

Tags: nghttp2

I am using nghttp2 to send APN2 notification. The basic code was taken from https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/blob/master/examples/client.c

The only difference from the above example is that I keep connection open for sending multiple notifications, but one at a time. Hence I do not call `nghttp2_session_terminate_session` from `on_stream_close_callback`. Instead I call `nghttp2_session_del` when connection is closed by the server.

This worked so far. However, recently our usage increased and I started getting assertion here in `nghttp2_session_pack_data` function.

https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/blob/master/lib/nghttp2_session.c#L7737

```
/* Current max DATA length is less then buffer chunk size */
  assert(nghttp2_buf_avail(buf) >= datamax);
```

The above assert is due to nghttp2 not able to allocate memory.

Do you think this due to I am not calling `nghttp2_session_terminate_session`. What would be right way to handle this?

Thanks